# File PUT'ed from Cordova FileTransfer to S3 contains unwanted metadata

Tags: amazon-s3, cordova-plugins, put

I was able to upload a video file from Cordova to S3 using:

```
options.fileKey = fileName;
options.fileName = fileName;
options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.httpMethod = "PUT";

ft.upload(videoURI, signedUploadUrl, ..., ..., options);
```

The problem is that the file is saved on S3 wrapped with this metadata:

```
--+++++
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_video.txt"; filename="my_video.txt"
Content-Type: video/mp4

<file-content>

--+++++--
```

How to save the plain content of the file without this text around it?

Answer (score 1):

That was not a problem, actually.

The problem was that I had the wrong Content-Type for the files on S3.
See the selected answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363144/how-can-i-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-cordova-filetransfer).