# Response empty while uploading files to Amazon S3 using Cordova FileTransfer?

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-transfer

I am using Cordova FileTransfer plugin to upload image file in Amazon S3 server. Here is my procedure of performing fileTransfer

1. I called my server with the photoURL and get the keys for submitting
   amazon s3 server which I included as key value pair in params
2. Then I am using the fileTransfer plugin for uploading the file with following codes.

   ```
       var options = new FileUploadOptions();
       options.fileKey = "file";
       options.fileName = fileName;
       options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
       options.chunkedMode = false;
       options.encodeURI= false;

       var headers={
           'X-Amz-Acl': 'public-read'
       };

       options.headers = headers;
       options.params = params;

       var ft = new FileTransfer();
       ft.upload(fileURL,form.action, win, fail, options)
   ```
3. The response returns to the win function returning json response

   ```
       bytesSent: 31968
       objectId: ""
       response: ""
       responseCode: 204
   ```

   The file is not uploaded and I am not getting any response URL of my image
4. I have used 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'  But its responding 412 error code and in Message 
   **Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data**. Why this is the response as I am sending speically to use image/jpeg content type?
5. Here I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363144/how-can-i-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-cordova-filetransfer?answertab=active#tab-top) By pull method. But It return in fails fuction. I get **error code 3** which say **MalformedXML** in body and error saying "**Write error: ssl=0x6d3c2c20: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer**"

Please someone help me to get what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: Yes. For android the response is null returned but for iOS response is okay.  
  

So for android the work around will be the 
   
   form.action + params.key;

And following code are enough for sending the file( 4, 5 points are ignored )

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey = "file";
   options.fileName = fileName;
   options.chunkedMode = false;

   options.params = params;

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For android the response is null returned but for iOS response is okay.

So for android the work around will be the

```
response = form.action + params.key;
```

And following code are enough for sending the file( 4, 5 points are ignored )

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileName;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        options.params = params;
```